# Error in loading JSON from itsdangerous file TimedJSONSerializer Token

Tags: python, authentication, token, serialization

I am currently working on authenticating my users. I checked out this blog - [RESTful Authentication with Flask](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) - and followed its steps to produce a piece of code I believed would serve my purpose. I wanted to use the Timed Json Serializer class for my particular use case. Below, I am creating an object of that class, generating a token and trying to load the data with it.

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer
user_id = 'fake1'
s = TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer(parser_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=3600)
token = s.dumps({'user_id' : user_id})
print(token)
print (s.loads(token))
```

I get the following callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQ2ODI3MjU3MSwiaWF0IjoxNDY4MjY4OTcxfQ.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiZmFrZTEifQ.Ch8y6BDMIIBdIGM0lmjdAimINvP3PnUmBpOp-jDW18w
  File "C:/Users/vaibhav/PycharmProjects/Coding/Coding.py", line 6, in <module>
    print (s.loads(token))
  File "C:\Users\vaibhav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 798, in loads
    self, s, salt, return_header=True)
  File "C:\Users\vaibhav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 752, in loads
    self.make_signer(salt, self.algorithm).unsign(want_bytes(s)),
  File "C:\Users\vaibhav\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 377, in unsign
    payload=value)
itsdangerous.BadSignature: Signature 'Ch8y6BDMIIBdIGM0lmjdAimINvP3PnUmBpOp-jDW18w' does not match
```

I have just created the token with an expiry of an hour and it gives me a BadSignature which indicates that the token does not match. The desired output would be:

```
{"user_id" : "fake1"}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall the package `itsdangerous` with `pip`. The statements used were:

```
pip uninstall itsdangerous
```

followed by:

```
pip install itsdangerous
```

Apparently, the file had been corrupted somehow causing it not to work properly.